# On the mgf of the Logistic Distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

So the Logistic Distribution pdf (w/ mean = 0 and shape parameter = 1) looks like this:
$$f_X(x)=\frac{e^{x}}{({1+e^{x}})^2}\;\;, \;\;-\infty<x<\infty$$ Now, I am interested in getting its moment-generating function (mgf). So here is what I have:
$$M_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\frac{e^{x}}{({1+e^{x}})^2}dx$$
So I let$$u=\frac{1}{1+e^x}\;\;,\;\;du=-\frac{e^x}{({1+e^{x}})^2}dx$$
Thus, I get
$$\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{u}-1\right)^tdu$$
Now, I do not know what to do next. The answer was given to be $B(t+1,t-1)\;,\;-1<t<1$ where $B(\dot\;,\dot\;)$ is the Beta function.

Can anyone help me? I will really appreciate it a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition,

$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1 u^{x-1}(1-u)^{y-1} \mathrm{d}u$$

Rewrite your last step as
$$\int_0^1 u^{-t}(1-u)^t \mathrm{d}u = B(1-t,t+1)=B(1+t,1-t) $$
where the last step follows from the symmetry of the Beta function.

Comment: Thanks!! Got it! It was my only misstep.I thought I was doing it incorrectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

In general the density (w/ mean = $\mu$ and shape parameter = $s$) looks like this:

$$\begin{align}
f(x;\mu,s)&=\frac{e^{-(x-\mu)/s}}{s\left(1+e^{-(x-\mu )/s}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{s\left(e^{(x-\mu)/(2s)}+e^{-(x-\mu )/(2s)}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{4s}\text{sech}^{2}\left(\frac {x-\mu}{2s}\right).
\end{align}$$

The mgf is
$$ \begin{align}
M(t)&=\mathbb E[e^{tx}]\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tx}\frac{e^{(x-\mu)/s}}{s\left(e^{(x-\mu)/s}+1\right)^2}dx\\
&=\int_{1}^{0}-\left(\frac{1}{u}-1\right)^{st}e^{\mu t} du\quad u=\frac{1}{1+e^{(x-\mu)/s}}\quad du=-\frac{e^{(x-\mu)/s}}{s\left(e^{(x-\mu)/s}+1\right)^2}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{u}-1\right)^{st} e^{\mu t}du\\
&=e^{\mu t}\int_{0}^{1}u^{-st}\left(1-u\right)^{st} du\\
&=e^{\mu t}B(1-st, 1+st)\\
\end{align}$$